# React Native - can't scroll inside ScrollView wrapped inside animated view on Android

Tags: android, react-native

I have a `<ScrollView />`, wrapped inside an Animatable.View (a wrapper for Animated.View with a few standard animations)

Like this:

```
<Animatable.View
            animation={this.state.businessSlide}
            duration={500}
            delay={this.state.delay}
            useNativeDriver={false}
            easing={"ease-in-cubic"}
            onAnimationEnd={this.handleBusinessPop}
          >
            <ScrollView
              style={{ width: "100%", alignSelf: "center", height: 175, zIndex: 999 }}
              contentContainerStyle={{ alignSelf: "center", justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center", flexGrow: 1 }}
              onScroll={(event) => this.businessScroll(event)}
              scrollEventThrottle={16}
            >
              {this.state.businessMerchants.map((merchant, index) => (
                <Business
                  merchant={merchant}
                  key={merchant.id}
                  isCurrentItem={index === this.state.currentItemIndex}
                />
              ))}
              <View style={{ height: 100 }} />
            </ScrollView>

          </Animatable.View>
```

The view slides in from the bottom the position.

I believe this is due to some sort of overlap or something, as if I set the translate distance to 0, (i.e. it animates to where it would be normally without the animated view), it scrolls fine.

This only happens on Android, iOS works as expected.

Comment: Im not sure if this would work but have you tried using Animated.ScrollView? That way you could animated the position of your scrollview directly. The problem is that Animated.View uses its own Pan Responder which on android can interfere with touches. You could also try adding pointerEvents:"none" to the Animated.View.

Comment: Did you test Animated.ScrollView except ScrollView?

Comment: You are using `height: 175` that might be the reason

Comment: In my case adding flexShrink: 1 to the Animated.View helped